# Generating Service Contract from a WSDL

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, contract-first, wscf

I have a WSDL that I need to generate a ServiceContract (OperationContract, DataContract)...

I have found a way to do it for [ASMX WebServices](http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2008/05/generating-c-web-service-skeleton-from.html) but can't seem to find how to do it in WCF.

I have tried running

```
svcutil AuthPartnerWSDL.wsdl  /i /messagecontract /tcv:version35
```

but the resulting interface doesn't deserialize the call coming in so all the request parameters to the service implementation are `null`

Comment: Small correction of terminology: what you're referring to as "webservices" are "ASMX Web Services", sometimes known as "ASP.NET Web Services". WCF services are web services if they use SOAP or REST.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contract first tool for WCF

http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/

Comment: even then, why would it be down voted? isn't it a valid answer?

Comment: It's valid, but if the answer was from someone else, it would be a fairly bad answer. It's not considereed good to just throw in a link. BTW, you might edit this answer to say a little more about this tool: why is it useful? How does it answer your question, etc.

Comment: Similar utility for VS2013, VS2017 here: https://github.com/WSCF/WSCF (VS2019 support TBD at the time of this comment)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the most updated WSDL that matches the current service definition.

Comment: both the client proxy and the ServiceContract are generated from the same wsdl file.